# Javascript not redirecting to URL

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have the following html & js functions that will take values from an input form then concatenate the data to the end of a url string and the goal is to re-direct the url but  my problem is that it is not re-directing. What am I doing wrong?

Heres the html

```
<form id="url">
            <input type="text" name="urlName">
            <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
        </form>
```

Heres the Javascript

```
function myFunction() {
    let myForm = document.getElementById("url");
    let formData = new FormData(myForm);
    EndOfUrl = sanitizeDomainInput(formData.get("urlName"));
    window.location = redirectLink(EndOfUrl);
    return false;
}

    function sanitizeDomainInput(input) {
        input = input || 'unknown.com'
        if (input.startsWith('http://')) {
            input = input.substr(7)
        }
        if (input.startsWith('https://')) {
            input = input.substr(8)
        }
        var regexp = new RegExp(/^(([a-zA-Z]{1})|([a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z]{1})|([a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]{1})|([0-9]{1}[a-zA-Z]{1})|([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-_]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]))\.([a-zA-Z]{2,6}|[a-zA-Z0-9-]{2,30}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})$/)
        return regexp.test(input) ? input : 'unknown.com'
    }

    function redirectLink(domain) {
        return `https://dashboard.getorda.com/signup/?state=${domain}`;
    }
```

Please help

Comment: `<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">`

Answer (score 0):

The return false in `myFunction` does nothing, you have to return false on the attribute itself if you want to prevent the form from submitting and ignoring your redirection.

```
<button onclick="myFunction();return false;">Try it</button>
```

or

```
<button onclick="return myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

or since there is no intention for the form to ever submit set the button type so that it doesn't submit the form.

```
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Comment: Do you think I should remove return false>

Answer (score 0):

Please update the button.

```
<button type='button' onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

The rest seems to be okay.

Answer (score -1):

Please move the button to the outside of the form.
When the button is inside of the form, it works as form submissions.
`myFunction` cannot run if the button is inside of the form.

```
<form id="url">
     <input type="text" name="urlName">
</form>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Comment: Makes sense. Its functioning now. Thank you!